# Ractive teardown/re-render with partials doesn't re-render partials

Tags: ractivejs

Here's the fiddle (sorry about the alerts) http://jsfiddle.net/PCcqJ/92/

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
    template: '#templateOne',
    partials: {
        aPartial: '<div>Oh look, the partial is rendered!</div>'
    }
});

function cb() {
    alert('but now we unrender');
    ractive.once('complete', function() {
        alert('we rendered again, and now you can\'t see the partial content');
    });
    ractive.render('container');
}

ractive.render('container');

ractive.once('complete', function() {
    alert('so we render the first time, and you can see the partial');
    ractive.unrender().then(cb);    
});
```

The partial here doesn't get re-rendered. Why is this? The partials are still in the partials object, and they have been unrendered, so what would prevent them from getting rendered again?

This fiddle renders, unrenders, and then re-renders, giving you an alert each time one of those happens.

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug! I've [raised an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/2041) so we can investigate. Depending on your situation, one possible workaround would be to teardown and reinstantiate rather than unrender/rerender, or (if you need to move the instance from one container element to another) using `ractive.insert()`: http://jsfiddle.net/Lzqr0prd/

Answer (score 0):

I made a working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/43gLqbku/1/

```
<div id='container'></div>


<script id="templateOne" type="x-template">
    {{>aPartial}}
</script>
```

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
        el:"#container",
    template: '#templateOne',
    partials: {
        aPartial: '<div>Oh look, the partial is rendered!</div>'
    }
});
function cb() {
    alert('but now we unrender');
    ractive.once('complete', function() {
        alert('we rendered again, and now you can\'t see the partial content');
    });
    ractive.render('container');
}

//ractive.partials.part = '<div>this is a partial</div>';
ractive.once('complete', function() {
    alert('so we render the first time, and you can see the partial');
    ractive.unrender().then(cb);    
});
```

1. you need to call ractive.once('completed') before calling render
2. you dont need to ractive.render("container"); under ractive code cause it is automaticly rendered when first run
3. in your jsfiddle the ractive you imported didnt work
4. you didnt include el:"#container" in your jsFiddle ractive code